# Data export from CE thingsboard

Tags: postgresql, post, thingsboard

Hi dear friends i want to send data from my ce thingsboard server to another Web server with post model anybody there can help me to solve this issue. And my another problem i want to access postgresql database from outside how i can, regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could do this using Rulechains. There is Rulenode called `REST API Call`:
   https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/external-nodes/#rest-api-call-node
2. First make sure the Postgresql Database is accessible via remote, then connect with a client of your choice e.g. pgAdmin, DBeaver..,
   https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Comment: Hi dear friend thanks for your response i create a rule chain rest api call and in endpoint filed i wrote my external server address that i want to send data's to it, in thingsboard rest api call debug in type mode is successfully but out type mode gives a error, after add rule chain there is another work to do?

Comment: What's the error message? Typically there is a hint upon what's wrong

Comment: Thanks again my dear friend i create a transformation script then rest api call and in debug mode i see data is sending from thingsboard correctly but there is error 400  or 405 or 300 and this is true because i haven't any web sever or database to received data's on other side thanks for your help God bless you